# Displaying thumbnails of posts on the home page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently developing my own theme for wordpress and would like to have a sidepanel that just displays the recent posts with a picture that has the title and a small excerpt inside of it. I'm struggling to figure out how to get it to work as calling the:

```
the_post_thumbnail_url
```

function on the front page/main page doesn't work as I want it to so I'm struggling on how to get it in the card below:

```
<div class="card bg-dark text-white">
<img src="..." class="card-img" alt="...">
<div class="card-img-overlay">
<h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
<p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
<p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Currently I have this as my recent posts which just displays the 10 most recent posts with a title and excerpt, but no picture since it just decides not to show:

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block">
 <div class="container sidebar">
 <h3 style="text-align: center; font-weight: 700;">Recent Posts</h3>
 <?php

 $result = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
 'numberposts' => 10,
 'category' => '',
 'post_status' => 'publish',
  ));

foreach( $result as $p ){
 ?>

 <div class="paddingarea text-dark">

 <a class="card-title" href="<?php echo get_permalink($p['ID']) ?>" style="font-weight:  600;"><?php echo $p['post_title']?></a><br />
 <p class="card-text"><?php echo excerpt(10); ?></p>
 </div>
 </div>
 <?php
 }
 ?>

 </div>
```

Comment: Check out my solution please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`the_post_thumbnail_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail_url/) displays the post thumbnail URL (where the *post* here refers to the global `$post`).

In your case, where you want to get the thumbnail URL of a specific post (within your `foreach`), you could use the [`get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) instead, which accepts a `$post` parameter (post ID or [`WP_Post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/) object).

```php
get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post );
```

Also, since you you want to *print* the thumbnail, you could use [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/), which returns the post thumbnail image tag to print instead of its url.

This would look like:

```php
// Get an array containing 10 most recent posts
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array(
  'numberposts' => 10,
  'category'    => '',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
) );

// Iterate over each post and print its thumbnail
foreach ( $recent_posts as $p ) {
  echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $p->ID );
}
```

You can read more about their differences:

- [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/)
- [`the_post_thumbnail_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail_url/)
- [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/)
- [`get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/)

That is, if you want to use your existing code with `wp_get_recent_posts()`.

Another approach, would be to create a new query to loop through your recent posts, using [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/), and then use WordPress functions as you would normally do in [The Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/).

```php
// Create a new query
$recent_posts_query = new WP_Query( array(
  'numberposts' => 10,
  'category'    => '',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
) );

if ( $recent_posts_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $recent_posts_query->have_posts() ) {
    $recent_posts_query->the_post();

    // Now you can use WordPress functions as you would normally do in The Loop
    echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';

    // Print the post thumbnail
    the_post_thumbnail();
  }
}
```